# Asp.net MVC4 Dynamic Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and have below issue with dynamic routing.

My url patterns will be

```
site.com/categorry1
site.com/categorry1/category2/category3
site.com/categorry1/model
site.com/model
site.com/search/products?model?xxx
site.com/common/getattributes?attname=123
```

Basically it is bit hard to identify the pattern of the urls so I have a common controll called catchall that split the url segments and redirect accordingly which is working fine

My route rule is below:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*url}", new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index" });
```

Now the question is how to call a fixed controller. As an example I need to call a controller called CommonController which has a method called getData.

I've added below rule (above the catchall) to the route but it comes up with 404.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Common", url: "{Common}/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "Common" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*url}", new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index" });
```

In short,

How to have a catch all controller to catch all url patterns while having another common controller which is only call if I call exactly the same controller name. How do I do this in the route mapping ?

Thanks

Comment: `url: "Common/{action}"` (not `{Common}/{action}`) if you wanting to call methods in `CommonController`

Comment: Oh.. I think this is the problem. Now it is working and let me test it and see all working as expected...

Comment: site.com/search/products?model?xxx   you sure there are two "?"